# Listbox.Height doesn't update on 1 PC, but does on all other PC's at the office

Tags: vba, listbox, userform, autodesk-inventor

I've ran into a problem I can't fix..
I use VBA 7.1 in Autodesk Inventor 2017.
During a macro, a Userform is being called.
I use 'UserForm_Initialize()' to fill some data in to the UserForm:
I fill up a listbox, change some labelcaptions, and position and resize some controls.
The UserForm gets resized by the height of a listbox on the form with this code:

```
HeightListbox = 12.7 + MaxRows * 12.7

ListBoxSelectiParts.Height = HeightListbox
UserFormSelectiParts.Height = HeightListbox + 80
CommandButtonOK.Top = HeightListbox + 22
CommandButtonCancel.Top = HeightListbox + 22
```

The strange thing is, I've tested this on about 5 PC's and it works great, except for 1 PC..
On that PC the all data is being filled in, the control resizing an repositioning is done, except for the listbox.height!
When I create a different button and hard code it with

```
ListBoxSelectiParts.Height = 300
```

It works, but it doesn't during the initialize..
Again, this works on all other PC's at my office..
All PC's are Windows 7 64bits. I noticed a difference in built versions with some PC's, but 2 PC's have the same built version as the problem PC and the code does work on those PC's..

Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try a reboot?

Comment: Sounds like there is a setting in AutoDesk that is inhibiting the initialize call. It could be a security setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reactions. I've done multiple reboots (I've been struggling with this for a week now :) ). If it can be a security setting, isn't it the strange that all the other controls get resized and moved in the Initialize call?

Answer (score 1):

I have included the listbox (making the listbox high enough) into a frame. Then, simply change the frame´s height. I put the frame's BorderStyle property in 0=fmBorderStyleNone